# I am reading two parquet files in same folder . both of them have same columns but few columns datatype is not matching

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

Unable to load same columns from two files under one folder . Few of the columns are bigint in one file and in another file they are double.Due to which i am facing error in reading files on folder level in Glue using pyspark

Comment: How are you loading the data? Do you have a crawler in place? Do you use the parquet or the Glue Meta Data API?

Comment: inp_df = sqlContext.read.options(header='True').parquet('s3://lly-edp-refined-us-east-2-dev/Geography/PARTITION_TS=202111/')

Comment: Lets take one column name humidity so it has value 4.5326 in one file and 2 in another file

Comment: And what error are you facing?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableLong cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableDouble

Comment: QueryExecutionException: Encounter error while reading parquet files. One possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted in the corresponding